# ggplot error using linetype and group aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make plot based on the following data

```
dt <- data.frame(ValuationDate = seq.Date(as.Date("2014-1-1"), 
                 as.Date("2014-7-1"), by = "month"), 
                 Adjuster = factor(c("Bob","Bob","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Bob")),
                 Paid = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), Incurred = c(3,5,9,9,10,8,7))
dt <- melt(dt, measure.vars = c("Paid", "Incurred"), 
           variable.name = "Value", value.name = "Amount")
dt
   ValuationDate Adjuster    Value Amount
1     2014-01-01      Bob     Paid      1
2     2014-02-01      Bob     Paid      2
3     2014-03-01      Sue     Paid      3
4     2014-04-01      Sue     Paid      4
5     2014-05-01      Sue     Paid      5
6     2014-06-01      Sue     Paid      6
7     2014-07-01      Bob     Paid      7
8     2014-01-01      Bob Incurred      3
9     2014-02-01      Bob Incurred      5
10    2014-03-01      Sue Incurred      9
11    2014-04-01      Sue Incurred      9
12    2014-05-01      Sue Incurred     10
13    2014-06-01      Sue Incurred      8
14    2014-07-01      Bob Incurred      7
```

For each ValuationDate, there is a "Paid" amount and an "Incurred" amount which I'd like to plot over time, associating each time period with an Adjuster.  When I try doing

```
#with grouping variable and linetype (error)
ggplot(data = dt) + geom_step(aes(x = ValuationDate, 
                                  y = Amount, group = Value, 
                                  color = Adjuster, linetype = Value))
```

I get "Error: geom_path: If you are using dotted or dashed lines, colour, size and linetype must be constant over the line"

However the following two plots work

```
#with grouping variable, without linetype
ggplot(data = dt) + geom_step(aes(x = ValuationDate, y = Amount,
                                  group = Value, color = Adjuster))
```

[image]

```
#with linetype, without grouping variable
ggplot(data = dt) + geom_step(aes(x = ValuationDate, y = Amount,
                                  color = Adjuster, linetype = Value))
```

[image]

What gives?

Comment: What output are you looking for? How many total lines, representing what?

Comment: My output should have two lines, very similar to the first graph I displayed.  The issue with that graph though, is that there's no distinction between what is "Paid" and what is "Incurred".

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a look at the [piece of code](https://github.com/cran/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-path-.r) that generates the error:

```
# Work out whether we should use lines or segments
attr <- ddply(munched, .(group), function(df) {
  data.frame(
    solid = identical(unique(df$linetype), 1),
    constant = nrow(unique(df[, c("alpha", "colour","size", "linetype")])) == 1
  )
})
solid_lines <- all(attr$solid)
constant <- all(attr$constant)
if (!solid_lines && !constant) {
  stop("geom_path: If you are using dotted or dashed lines",
    ", colour, size and linetype must be constant over the line",
    call.=FALSE)
}
```

So if there are at least two different `linetype`s, all other aes should be unique. I cannot say why exactly this limitation is present, probably it caused some rendering related issues.

You can make the lines distinguishable by other means, e.g. by varying `size` or `alpha` instead of `linetype`. Another possibility would be adding

```
geom_point(aes(x = ValuationDate, y = Amount, group = Value, shape = Value), size = 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use separate geom_step calls for each unique Value x Adjuster segment.

```
gg <- ggplot()
for (i in 1:6) gg <- gg + 
  geom_step(data=subset(your_dt, Segment==i), 
            aes(x=ValuationDate, y=Amount, color=Adjuster, linetype=Value, group=i))
```

Produces (on call to `gg`):
[image]

To rig it to get continuous stepped lines (i.e. the output you want), you have to insert some dummy/duplicate rows. I did that manually, but depending on how often you are doing this you'll probably want a function to insert these rows. `Segment` can be easily calculated by comparing Adjuster and Value to the prior row.

your_dt:

```
   ValuationDate Adjuster    Value Amount DummyRow Segment
1       1/1/2014      Bob     Paid      1       no       1
2       2/1/2014      Bob     Paid      2       no       1
3       3/1/2014      Bob     Paid      2      yes       1
4       3/1/2014      Sue     Paid      2      yes       2
5       3/1/2014      Sue     Paid      3       no       2
6       4/1/2014      Sue     Paid      4       no       2
7       5/1/2014      Sue     Paid      5       no       2
8       6/1/2014      Sue     Paid      6       no       2
9       7/1/2014      Sue     Paid      6      yes       2
10      7/1/2014      Bob     Paid      6      yes       3
11      7/1/2014      Bob     Paid      7       no       3
12      1/1/2014      Bob Incurred      3       no       4
13      2/1/2014      Bob Incurred      5       no       4
14      3/1/2014      Bob Incurred      5      yes       4
15      3/1/2014      Sue Incurred      5      yes       5
16      3/1/2014      Sue Incurred      9       no       5
17      4/1/2014      Sue Incurred      9       no       5
18      5/1/2014      Sue Incurred     10       no       5
19      6/1/2014      Sue Incurred      8       no       5
20      7/1/2014      Sue Incurred      8      yes       5
21      7/1/2014      Bob Incurred      8      yes       6
22      7/1/2014      Bob Incurred      7       no       6
```