# Customising line type in adjusted survival curves ggadjustedcurves (survminer, ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival

I'm trying to plot an adjusted survival curve, but struggling with changing the line types by group. I'm able to customise other aspects of the plot using typical ggplot2 language, but I've hit a wall with changing line type.

Example:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

fit2 <- coxph( Surv(stop, event) ~ size + strata(rx), data = bladder )

ggadjustedcurves(fit2,
                 variable = "rx", 
                 data = bladder,
                 method = "average",
                 palette = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9"),
                 size = 1.3,
                 legend = "right",
                 legend.title = expression(bold("Legend title")),
                 xlab = "Time",
                 font.legend = 12) +
  theme(legend.text.align = 0.5)
```

I've tried adding in:

```
geom_line( aes( linetype = c(1, 2) )
add.params = list(linetype = c(1, 2))
```

and just

```
linetype = c(1, 2)
```

but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to look at the code.

```
ggadjustedcurves
```

It appears that `ggadjustedcurves` passes all it arguments on to helper functions that depend on the "method" argument, in this case "average", so now look at that (hidden) function:

```
 getAnywhere( ggadjustedcurves.average )
```

And note that there is no provision to accept additional arguments beyond the few that are defined in the "master function", i.e. no use of R's ellipsis mechanism or specifications of other possible aes-arguments besides size. (It's also not using `geom_line`.) So you need to change *both* the master function *and* the helper function to accept a "linetype" argument. Here I show how to modify the helper function (although this needs to be done to the `ggadjustedcurves` function as well and maybe the rest of the helper functions if you want this to be completely general):

```
assignInNamespace('ggadjustedcurves.average',  

  function (data, fit, variable, size = 1, ..., linetype=linetype) 
    {
    time <- surv <- NULL
    lev <- sort(unique(data[, variable]))
    pred <- survexp(as.formula(paste("~", variable)), data = data, 
                    ratetable = fit)
    curve <- data.frame(time = rep(c(0, pred$time), length(lev)), 
                        variable = factor(rep(lev, each = 1 + length(pred$time))), 
                        surv = c(rbind(1, pred$surv)))
    ggplot(curve, aes(x = time, y = surv, color = variable)) + 
        geom_step(size = size, ..., linetype=linetype)  # not geom_line
    }, 
   pos="package:survminer")
```

[image]

If you do an SO search on "geom_segment linetype" you find that `geom_segment` (which is what `geon_step` uses)  is not constructed in a manner that makes it easy to give it short vectors to modify "contiguous" lengths of step function results. See [ggplot error using linetype and group aesthetics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005299/ggplot-error-using-linetype-and-group-aesthetics) . This means you would need to use a `for-loop` or `lapply` to build separate "step-curves" if you need different line types.

Comment: Is there any way to add patients at risk below the plots? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65158418/add-patients-at-risk-to-adjusted-survival-curves-in-ggplot2-in-r)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be related to the primary question. If you've done a search on the topic, then why not try composing reproducible example and then also review the nominated prior questions. If none of them answer your question then hit "Submit".

Comment: thanks for your answer. I composed 2 separate questions in 2 different coding manners [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65153421/add-at-risk-table-and-95-confidence-intervals-to-adjusted-survival-curves-using) and here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65158418/add-patients-at-risk-to-adjusted-survival-curves-in-ggplot2-in-r) but I did not get an answer so I added a comment here if you could help. Upvoted your current answer.  Appreciate any advice

Comment: Searching on "survminer risk table" which I suggested. brings up 20 hits.